# Yellow underlines for libraries due to Pylance, even though they work without problem

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
import discord # it's yellow underlined
print(discord.__version__) # ' out: 2.0.0
```

Pylance can't find anything about it. Same thing happens with pygame and numpy too. And probably with all libraries. I tried in both 3.10 and 3.9. My interpreter path if needed: `C:\Python\Python310\python.exe`

Comment: Is there any tooltip or warning? Probably thinks those are not installed properly.

Comment: @tobias_k No, all functions are working. It says Import "discord" could not be resolved by Pylance(reportMissingImports) when i hover over import discord

Comment: So it's an error with how Pylance is configured (it is probably using a different interpreter). Add this information to your question.

Comment: Have you restarted your VSCode?

Comment: @matszwecja yes, i tried with different versions of python too

Answer (score 1):

Because the location of the package you installed successfully may not be the same as the python environment you are using.

- First, open the command palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- then search for **Python:Select Interpreter**
- Choose the correct interpreter (the one you installed the package with)

  **Or**
- Choose the interpreter you want to use,
- then create a new terminal to activate the environment.
- Finally install the packages you need for the current environment in a new terminal.

***Another way:***

Add the following to your **setting.json** file:

```json
    "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportMissingImports": "none",
    }
```